# When do Bank Accounts become dormant in Turkey?

Tags: bank-account, turkey

Does anyone know / have an idea about dormant bank accounts rules in Turkey? For example How many year should the account be inactive for account to be classified as dormant account? Once the account has become dormant, what happens to the funds?

Is there a way the Account Owner can reactivate his account and get it operational?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 10 years. If your account is inactive for 10 years its funds will be transferred to state regulatory commission called TMSF. Read more here: http://www.todayszaman.com/newsDetail_getNewsById.action;jsessionid=51369E62EA8A8810EED65A31D256031D?newsId=236579

To prevent your funds from transferring to state like that you'll have to contact your bank.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but are there is possibility to retrieve the money from TMSF again?

Comment: Nope, there is no "official" way to retrieve the money back after it has been transferred to TMSF. I'm not sure but you might want to ask a lawyer for professional help, a court case might be helpful if the money is a big sum.